# Include my USB device driver in Windows Update?

Tags: windows, usb, driver

How would an OEM go about getting their USB device driver added to Windows Update, so that it will be downloaded and installed automatically when the device is connected to the PC? In our case, if it matters, it will be a custom USB device class, and the driver will wrap WinUSB.

Is it possible to do this for Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10? 32 and 64-bit.

What keywords (for searching) and concepts should I be aware of?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. How to register with Microsoft is off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB, surely there's more to it (including programming steps) than just registering with Microsoft. [On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) lists `a specific programming problem`, `software tools commonly used by programmers`, and `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`. Seems to me this this question fits all of those.

Comment: You've got two parts: Getting your driver INF signed, and getting the signed driver bundle added to Windows Update.  Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463010.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that with MS OS 2.0 Descriptors, you can get WinUSB attached to your Device *and* show a custom name in the Device Manager in Windows 8.1 and later, so (with some qualifications) there is no reason to even have a driver.  Also, it's possible to sign a driver yourself and distribute it to users without getting Microsoft's permission or registering the driver with them; see my article on [signing](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing).

Answer (score 0):

The question is misguided. The interface to WinUSB lives in userspace - not kernel space - so that DLL will be a library that lives in userspace; it won't be a driver.

The device will report via its device descriptors to Windows that it can use the WinUSB driver, so Windows won't look for its wrapper.

Comment: User-mode device drivers are still device drivers, and can still be distributed via Windows Update AFAIK.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about [WinUSB Devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450799(v=vs.85).aspx) introduced in Windows 8.  The OP's device supports Windows 7, so it is unlikely to be using that particular mechanism.

Comment: This should really be an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39397845/edit) to the original question, or a comment response.

Comment: @IInspectable, you mean my answer here should've been a comment/edit? Why?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be an answer to any of the questions you asked. I was assuming you were providing additional information, which should then be part of the question.